# Trying to just get Text from Href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to re-iterate over code. If i print trackname i get full name, then next line does nothing? really struggling here.

Help appreciated into what i should do

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/tracks/', "html.parser")

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

# only finding one track
# soup.table to find all links for days racing
#harness_table = soup.row
# scraps a href that is an incomplete URL that im trying to get to

tracks = soup.find(class_="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 content")

lists = []

links = tracks.find_all('a')

#Gets each track
for a in links:
    lists.append(base_url+a["href"])

# track1 = []
#purpose - just to get track name before going over other data
for link in lists:
  webpage = requests.get(link)
  track = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
  trackname = track.find_all(class_="pageTitle")
  track1 = trackname.get_text()
  print(trackname)
```

Comment: what do you mean next line does nothing? Actually, you should be getting an error, as `find_all` will return a list, and you use `.get_text()` on a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `find_all`, it returns a list of the elements with whatever tags and attributes you want it to find. So you'll need to get the text from the first element. Or you can just use `find` and that'll return the first tag/attribute.

so try altering to this:

```
#purpose - just to get track name before going over other data
for link in lists:
  webpage = requests.get(link)
  track = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
  trackname = track.find(class_="pageTitle")
  try:
      track1 = trackname.get_text()
  except:
      print ('No class="pageTitle" found.')
      track1 = ''
  print(track1)
No class="pageTitle" found.
```

**Output:**

```
Racing
Tracks
Albany
Albion Park
Albury
Ararat
Armidale
Bacchus Marsh
Ballarat
Bankstown
Bathurst
Benalla
...
```

Comment: want to exc excluding "Racing" and "tracks". i'm stuck again
`for link in lists:
  webpage = requests.get(link)
  track = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
  Barriertable = track.select(".mBarrier")
  trackname = track.find(class_="pageTitle")
  try:
      track1 = trackname.get_text()
  except:
      print('No class="pageTitle" found.')
      track1 = ''
  for th in Barriertable:
      td = th.find_all('th')
      row = [i.text for i in td]
      print(track1, row)`
This is printing barrier number. I want to exclude wins and starts. WANT TO LOOP OVER ROWS AFTER